# Implementing a never ending matrix formula on python for curve fitting

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, curve-fitting

I'm trying to write a program that can solve the general regression formula:
[So I'm trying to implement this matrix equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8LDY.png), is there anyway to do this such as to let the user decide how big it can be, without me making more and more if conditions (so just one piece of code that collapses to the matrix that the user wishes for)?
Code:

```
    #Solving the general matrix for the coefficients
if 3 == n:
    a = np.array([[np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[1])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[2]))],
                    [np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[2])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[2],FL[2]))]])
    b = np.array([np.sum(np.multiply(FL[0],FL[1])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[0],FL[2]))])
    x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
if 4 == n:
    a = np.array([[np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[1])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[2])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[3]))],
                    [np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[2])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[2],FL[2])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[2],FL[3]))],
                    [np.sum(np.multiply(FL[1],FL[3])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[2],FL[3])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[3],FL[3]))]])
    b = np.array([np.sum(np.multiply(FL[0],FL[1])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[0],FL[2])),np.sum(np.multiply(FL[0],FL[3]))])
    x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8LDY.png) In this code Phi_0 corresponds to FL[i=1] and FL[0] corresponds to y.

Comment: Hello @Essam, if you feel my answer below did in fact answered your doubts, consider marking it so the question can be closed :)

Comment: It does answer the question even though I implemennted it differently in the end, thank you.

Comment: You can answer your own question by the way. Perhaps your solution is better and can add value to the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the algorithm independent of the order of the polynomial. The easiest way is using `for` loops, although these will be slow (since they don't exploit NumPy's vectorization).
Here is a reproducible example with random data:

```
import numpy as np
# Order of polynomial
n = 5
# Random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1)
# Input arrays
phi = np.random.random((100,n))
y = np.random.random(100)
# Output arrays
a = np.zeros((n,n))
b = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    b[i] = np.sum(y * phi[:,i])
    for j in range(i,n):
        # Exploit that matrix is diagonal
        a[i,j] = a[j,i] = np.sum(phi[:,i] * phi[:,j])
# Coefficients array
x = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```